# Find if certain values have certain other parameters associated with it in a R data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to find out if certain values are associated with each category. I have a vector x <- c("Jay Ambiga","Ameen Agent"). For each value in x I want to know if the they have Coffee Shop and Restaurant associated with it. I was using grepl on description to find out if it the word Coffee or Restaurant but I am not sure how to get a final result which looks like this,

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(Date = c("Ledger:", "44718", "44737", "44768", 
                                    "44768", "Ledger:", "44564", "44564", "44567", "44567", "44662", 
                                    "44687", "44743", "44743", "44758", "44758"), Particulars = c("Ameen Agent", 
                                                                                                  "To", "To", "To", "By", "Jay Ambiga", "To", "By", "To", "By", 
                                                                                                  "To", "To", "By", "By", "To", "By"), Description = c("1-Jan-22 to 12-Oct-22", 
                                                                                                                                                       "UOB SGD A/C - Restaurant", "UOB SGD A/C - Restaurant", 
                                                                                                                                                       "UOB SGD A/C - Restaurant", "Agent Fee", "1-Jan-22 to 12-Oct-22", 
                                                                                                                                                       "UOB SGD A/C - Coffee Shop", "Purchase of Materials - Others", 
                                                                                                                                                       "UOB SGD A/C - Coffee Shop", "Purchase of Materials - Liquor & Cigarette", 
                                                                                                                                                       "UOB SGD A/C - Restaurant", "UOB SGD A/C - Restaurant", 
                                                                                                                                                       "Purchase of Materials - Others", "Purchase of Materials - Others", 
                                                                                                                                                       "UOB SGD A/C - Restaurant", "Purchase of Materials - Groceries"
                                                                                                  ), Vch_Type = c(NA, "Payment", "Payment", "Payment", "Journal", 
                                                                                                                  NA, "Payment", "Purchase", "Payment", "Purchase", "Payment", 
                                                                                                                  "Payment", "Purchase", "Purchase", "Payment", "Purchase"), Vch_No = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "1150", "1255", "1415", "39", NA, "13", "4671", "62", "9", "879", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "992", "11042022", "06052022", "1361", "16072022"), Debit = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "50", "300", "1000", NA, NA, "3447.5", NA, "258", NA, "293.39999999999998", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "880", NA, NA, "20", NA), Credit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "1000", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, "3447.5", NA, "258", NA, NA, "293.39999999999998", "880", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, "20"), Category = c("Ameen Agent", "Ameen Agent", "Ameen Agent", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Ameen Agent", "Ameen Agent", "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga", "Jay Ambiga")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
ans <- df[, .(temp = paste0(Description, collapse = ";")), by = .(Category)]
ans[, has_both := as.logical(
        sapply(temp, function(x) grepl("restaurant", x, ignore.case = TRUE)) * 
        sapply(temp, function(x) grepl("coffee shop", x, ignore.case = TRUE)))][, temp := NULL][]
#       Category has_both
# 1: Ameen Agent    FALSE
# 2:  Jay Ambiga     TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It works as expected. Could you please help me understand what the brackets [ ] at the end do?

Comment: they print the current object to the console. You can remove them in your production code